# How find an value in to all table postgress

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Suppose to have this word 'student' , I need to return all tables that contains the 'student' word. I need something like this:

```
select *
from information_schema.tables t 
where column ='student';
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: please show some sample data and expected results for that sample data; it is unclear if you want to search the table definitions or table data or both

Comment: The `S` in SQL stands for structured.... And you want to find things the unstructured way ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want *tables*, you would use:

```
select *
from information_schema.tables t 
where table_name like '%student%';
```

If you want *columns*, you would use the right metadata table and use:

```
select *
from information_schema.columns c
where column_name like '%student%';
```

Comment: my question is not to have the 'column name' but I need to check if in all table and columns there  are the value 'student'

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find the string 'students' or any version thereof in the database. Well there is no simple query that will give you that. So what you need to to select from the information schema **all columns names** having a string type definition and with those build a query for every column. The routine to do that is not overly complex or large providing you need only standard columns types. That no user defined types, no JSON(B), XML, or hstore types. You can try:

```
do $$
declare 
    k_sql_base constant text = $stmt$ 
                                 select '%1$s' table_schema,'%2$s' table_name,'%3$s' column_name
                                   from %1$I.%2$I  where lower(%3$I) like '%4$s' limit 1;
                               $stmt$;  
    k_search_text text = '%students%'; 
                                           
    c_text_cols cursor for 
        select col.table_schema
             , col.table_name
             , col.column_name 
          from information_schema.columns col
         where col.data_type in ('text', 'character varying')
           and col.table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
    
    l_table_rec   record;      
    l_search_stmt text; 

begin 
   for l_table_rec in c_text_cols
   loop
       l_search_stmt = format(k_sql_base
                             ,l_table_rec.table_schema
                             ,l_table_rec.table_name
                             ,l_table_rec.column_name
                             ,k_search_text
                             ) ;
       execute l_search_stmt into l_table_rec;
       if l_table_rec.table_schema is not null then  
           raise notice 'Found in: %.%.%',l_table_rec.table_schema
                                         ,l_table_rec.table_name
                                         ,l_table_rec.column_name;       
       end if;
    end loop;
end;
$$;
```